# What is the big-O performance of calling get(Range) with respect to the size of ranges? Why?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I want to know the Big O value of this code for the method get(Range) for ranges

I think it should be O(N) N-> ranges values upto 1...N

```
Range get(Range r) {
  Range lower = ranges.lower(r);
  Range higher = ranges.higher(r);
  if (ranges.contains(r)) {
    return r;
  }
  if (lower != null && lower.end >= r.start) {
    return lower;
  }
  if (higher != null && higher.start <= r.end) {
    return higher;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ranges.contains` is implemented in `O(f(n))`, the running time of your algorithm is `O(f(n))`. Because the other constraints will be checked in `O(1)` and each range is defined by two integer numbers here.

Comment: thanks I thought it would be O(n) where n is the range of the numbers

Comment: @Darshak Since we don't know the time complexity of `ranges.contains` (since it hasn't been provided) we can just say that it's time complexity is `f(n)`, which may well be linear.